# For loop statement cannot perform this query in Oracle 7.3.4

Tags: oracle, plsql

My Oracle Database version 7.3.4 (yes, is old but is what the client have) cannot perform this query in a FOR LOOP statement. As SQL I can do that.

I think its because the inline query in where condition (max).

With Oracle version 11g I don't have this problem.

```
  ...
     BEGIN
       FOR L IN (SELECT b.col1, SUM (b.pond) AS pond
                 FROM (SELECT s.status
                             ,s.col1
                             ,j.grpid
                             ,NVL (j.pond, -1) pond
                             ,COUNT ( * ) counter
                       FROM status s, sysstatus j
                       WHERE s.col1 = 4400390
                         AND s.state = 'S'
                         AND s.status = j.sysstatusid
                         AND datet || hour = (SELECT MAX (s1.datet) || MAX (LPAD (s1.hour, 5, 0))
                                              FROM status s1, sysstatus j1
                                              WHERE s1.col1 = 4400390 AND s1.state = 'S' AND s1.status = j1.sysstatusid AND j1.grpid = j.grpid)
                       GROUP BY s.status
                               ,s.col1
                               ,j.grpid
                               ,j.pond) b
                 GROUP BY b.col1)
       LOOP
          NULL;
       END LOOP;
    END;
...
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Error (when 'L' is the FOR LOOP statement):

```
ORA-06550: line 48, column 20:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 67, column 20:
PLS-00364: loop index variable 'L' use is invalid
ORA-06550: line 67, column 13:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Comment: Please show us the error code or why it doesn't work

Comment: @kevinsky I added the error

Comment: I don't see where the `L` is in the code you posted. Which line is line 67?

Comment: In the subquery `b`, you're aliasing the column to be `pond_`.  But in the outer query, you're doing a `sum( b.pond )` which shouldn't be valid.  You'd need to `sum(b.pond_)` or have a separate `pond` column.  I'd expect a different syntax error though.  I also can't imagine that it's a good idea to use `count` as a column alias-- normally you'd use something that wasn't a reserved word.  In this case, though, you're not actually using the `count(*)` anywhere so you'd want to remove it.

Comment: your client needs to upgrade so you can support them

Comment: Try using EXPLICIT cursor. I cannot find anything on that old a version but it is likely implicit cursors didn't exist in version 7.  After all Oracle 7 initially releases in 1992 and Oracle 8 in 1997.